# Spreadtrum (Vendor ID 1782) Issues Connecting to adb

Tags: android, adb

I have a phone which is detected by adb on a Mac, but not on my machine.  By "not detected", I mean that it does show up in lsusb, but "adb devices" reports a blank list of devices:

`adb devices
List of devices attached`

I have tried the following:

- Switching USB Cables
- Ensuring that device is in USB Debug Mode
- Factory resetting the device
- Adding the vendor ID (1782) to /etc/udev/rules.d
- Adding an entry to the ~/.android/adb_usb.ini file (is this necessary?)
- Multiple adb start-server and adb kill-server sequences
- Multiple reboots (and  "sudo udevadm control --reload-rules")
- Ran "android update adb", which erases the entry in ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

Pertinent Info:

- Running Ubuntu 14.04
- Entry in lsusb which is added when I plug in the device:

`Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1782:5d01 Spreadtrum Communications Inc.`

- Line within /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules :

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1782", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`

- Output of tail -f /var/log/syslog when plugging in this device

  `Jul 17 18:40:12 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1289.390363] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
  Jul 17 18:40:12 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1289.390439] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
  Jul 17 18:40:12 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1289.594502] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
  Jul 17 18:40:12 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1289.798588] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 7, error -71
  Jul 17 18:40:13 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1290.094956] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
  Jul 17 18:40:13 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1290.111786] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1782, idProduct=5d01
  Jul 17 18:40:13 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1290.111797] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
  Jul 17 18:40:13 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1290.111802] usb 3-2: Product: DASH JR
  Jul 17 18:40:13 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1290.111808] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: BLU
  Jul 17 18:40:13 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1290.111813] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 19761202
  Jul 17 18:40:13 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1290.112433] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
  Jul 17 18:40:13 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1290.112598] scsi6 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
  Jul 17 18:40:13 josh-N56VJ mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2"
  Jul 17 18:40:13 josh-N56VJ mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 9 was not an MTP device
  Jul 17 18:40:14 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1291.112557] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Spreadtr umopenphone        02 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
  Jul 17 18:40:14 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1291.113091] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
  Jul 17 18:40:14 josh-N56VJ kernel: [ 1291.115046] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk`

I can debug other devices using the same USB port and same cable without an issue, but I'm unsure why this phone won't connect.

Other related issues:

- [Android: adb does not recognize phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252432/android-adb-does-not-recognize-phone)
- [adb devices does not show my device every now and then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910107/adb-devices-does-not-show-my-device-every-now-and-then)
- [Problem to run my application on a real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580133/problem-to-run-my-application-on-a-real-device/16440639#16440639)

The first link appears similar to this issue, but I don't see any resolution.  Does adb consider a list of devices other than what is in the udev rules?  Is something else grabbing this device and keeping adb from noticing it?

**EDIT** - Confirmed that I am a member of the plugdev group:
`josh@josh-N56VJ:~/Development$ groups
josh adm dialout cdrom sudo audio dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare inpdev`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved, with this universal rule, thanks to this extremely helpful answer:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACES}=="*:ff420?:*", MODE="0666"
```

[ADB not detecting device samsung i777 in ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887524/adb-not-detecting-device-samsung-i777-in-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1)

Thanks to @alex-p

Additional Info:

Phone = Blu Dash Jr

**EDIT** 
I also needed to manually add the vendor ID (1782) to the ~/.android/adb_usb.ini file, as follows:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x1782
```

Still not sure where the vendor ID list is *supposed* to be edited since the file tells me not to, but this works.

Comment: This also works with Intex Cloud FX which also has vendorID = 1782 (and deviceID = 5d04).

Comment: Thank you! this is the only solution which worked for me after trying out tens of them.